# "Больше" - это выше или объемнее?

Tags: значение-слов

Если сравнивать, предположим, сумоиста и баскетболиста, к кому корректнее применить слово "больше"? Если применять сравнительную степень, к какому параметру применить его корректнее - к высоте или объему?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147829/discussion-on-question-by-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0):

"Больше" - это как правило объемнее, по размеру во все стороны. Но и высота также может пониматься в качестве объема.

В первую очередь объем.
Потом уже высота.

Comment: Больше - это вообще не про объемность. Что весит больше: воздушный шарик или шарик подшипника? У чего плотность больше: у воды или у кирпича? Без указания, что измеряется нельзя сказать, что больше.

Comment: @Буратино под объемом я имел ввиду распространенное использование "большой" в речи.
Возьмем шар с водой на 50 литров:
- Большой шар.
Также, если взять измерить объем дома, например три млн литров, также можно сказать, что этот дом "большой"